# Very High RAM usage while running simple LibGDX Project on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, android-emulator, ram

So, I created a libGDX project in android studio and gave it one image to show on screen, but once it ran on the emulator its kept increasing RAM Uage by the emulator till the point it has used almost all avaiable RAM?
How can a simple image rendering on Emulator use this much RAM
Please Help me with this
Here are some pictures that might assist you
[Here is an image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd7fn.png)

[Here is the image of Emulator and Task Mananger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eGht.png)

Comment: Basic rule of thumb: "`new`" should never appear in `render()` or anything indirectly or directly called by `render()`.

Answer (score 1):

Move `new Texture(...)` to the `create()` function, it is called only once.

render() is called **multiple times per second**, calling `new Texture(...)` in this method will constantly create new textures which are stored in RAM.

This is what causes your RAM usage to increase so fast.